# nest query returns weird results. elasticsearch

Tags: c#, .net, json, elasticsearch, nest

This is my client code:

**settings**

```
var defaultSettings = new ConnectionSettings(
    uri: new System.Uri("http://localhost:9200")
);

defaultSettings.SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(s => {
    s.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});

defaultSettings.SetConnectionStatusHandler(c => {
    if(!c.Success) throw new Exception(c.ToString());
});

defaultSettings.SetDefaultIndex("projects");
```

**executing code**

```
public ActionResult Search(String searchTerm) {
    var result = this.searchClient.Search<ProjectIndexModel>(
        descriptor: new SearchDescriptor<ProjectIndexModel>().Index("projects").AllTypes().Query(
            query: q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(searchTerm)
        )
    ));

    // or
    /* 
    var results = this.searchClient.Search<ProjectIndexModel>(s =>
        s.Index("projects").Type("project").Query(q => 
            q.Term(f => f.ProblemDefinition, searchTerm) || 
            q.Term(f => f.Name, searchTerm) ||
            q.Term(f => f.SuggestedSolution, searchTerm) ||
            q.Term(f => f.Initiator, searchTerm)
        )
    );        
    */

    return Json(result.Documents.ToList());
}
```

Indexing is launched at application start:

```
foreach(var project in this.dbContext.Projects) {
    var indexModel = Mapper.Map<ProjectIndexModel>(project);
    searchClient.Index(indexModel, "projects", "project", indexModel.Id.ToString());
}
```

[Indexes](https://gist.github.com/abirdd/eb81dc5a0a363b448f83#file-indexes-json) are present in database (that's not quite the same as I have now, but the schema stayed the same).

**what have I tried**:

Controller action returns (default) **10 hits** of 11 documents. It's like searching is ignored entirely, without visible errors.

`Fiddler` gave positive result (1 hit) both for `{host:9200}/_search` and `{host:9200}/projects/project/_search` **POST** requests with query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "original"
        }
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry I do not know c#. But if you don't specify a default field, in a query string query, you'll end up searching accross all fields. And if you don't specify a default operator, you will search for health OR care. Thus, any of those words anywhere in the document will make it a match. (I don't have access to the links provided, here, so it's just a guess)

Comment: But my intent is exactly to search across all fields. Why it returns results then if there are no matches?

Comment: Maybe there is Health or care on another field, on those docs. Even something like "I care for ducks" on any field of your doc will match. Are you positive that none of those two words are present in some of the matching docs?

Comment: No, there are no words like that in other documents. I seed data with the task and most part of those documents have identical values.

Comment: Sorry, not much more I can think of without seeing the docs and the index mapping. Just that your query is probably not taken into account. It would return all docs but only return 10 because it's the default size limit in ES.

Comment: Oh! Alright. At least I know why 10:) Don't know why links are unavailable? Can you follow them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was not in `NEST`. After exploring the `results.ConnectionStatus.ToString()`, which showed a hit as `Fiddler` did, I found that problem was in my client code. I overlooked that I was sending `POST` without `{searchTerm: $scope.searchTerm}` specified:

```
$http({
    url: '/projects/search',
    method: "POST",
    data: { searchTerm: $scope.searchTerm }
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.projects = data.documents;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('error: ' + data);
});
```